# Using touch screen with non-native aspect ratio

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen, aspect-ratio, dosbox

I have a laptop with touch screen (an Asus T100) with Windows 8, and I've downloaded a retro adventure game running using Dosbox (Gabriel Knight 1), which has a different aspect ratio from the screen.

When I play in full screen is displayed properly (with black bars on the sides), but I have an issue with touch screen: it acts as if the screen was actually stretched -- to get the cursor near the edge, I need to actually touch within the black bars.

Is there any simple way to fix it (other than playing in windowed mode)?